# Did Kylo Ren canonically get another helmet before The Rise of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, kylo-ren, galaxys-edge

In *The Last Jedi*, Kylo Ren smashes up his helmet, and in *The Rise of Skywalker*, he rebuilds it after retrieving the pieces. But in *Rise of the Resistance*, which takes place between the two films, he's wearing a helmet again:

[image: Image of a Kylo Ren animatronic from Rise of the Resistance]

While this was probably done due to real-world considerations, such as the expense of making a realistic unmasked animatronic, or some aspect of Adam Driver's image rights, is there an in-universe explanation for this?

Comment: Noting that this is a fairground attraction I suspect the answer is "nope"

Comment: "*No. Poe's fighter is just a new one with his usual paint job. The Kylo helmet thing is a story for another time"* Sayeth the Lucasfilm Story Group - [Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/missingwords/status/1149468750627799040)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been (tangentially) addressed by Matt Martin of the Lucasfilm Story Group. This is a 'replacement helmet' whose story has yet to be told.

> **Q.** *Could you address a thing in my beloved SW Adventures series? In 2020 edition #2 we have Kylo as Supreme Leader, so it's post-TLJ, but he wears his helmet from TFA and before times. He had second one that he lost somehow before TRoS or is it some kind of mistake?*
>
> **MM:** *It’s set around the same time as Galaxy’s Edge where he’s also got a helmet. The details behind that **replacement helmet** have yet to be told.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/missingwords/status/1335364964328951809)</sup></sub>

and

> **MM:** *Back up helmet? (It’s a story that’s yet to be told.)*
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/missingwords/status/1167426450078797825)</sup></sub>

That being said, it's actually unlikely it will be addressed (at all) since it was merely an out-of-universe decision based on kids liking Kylo's helmet.

> **MM:** *For what it’s worth, I’d originally assumed we’d go helmetless for this but **since SWA is more for kids and kids dig the helmet, I figured this was a good choice given the precedent set by SWGE.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/missingwords/status/1335364964328951809)</sup></sub>